# Mantaflow Initial Velocity 2.83 vs 2.9

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm working on some explosions and have been using the initial velocity for some of it. When I installed 2.9 it seems like this setting is either not working, or is very much different. I can stick with 2.83, but I recently got 3070 which didn't work with 2.8 and obviously it would speed stuff up.

Thanks

Comment: In what way is it "very much different"? There was a patch applied due to the initial velocity when switching a flow on/off being incorrect (it would be zero the first time and based on the last time it was 'on' on subsequent times) but that should have been 'fixed' - so I would expect a difference. See https://developer.blender.org/T80833 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194591/29586

Comment: Basically the initial velocity, on smoke and fire, was about 10x less. So I amped up the force from 3 to 30 and it looks more or less the same as in 2.83. It also seems far more sensitive to any increase in Sampling Substeps, but I haven't done tons of testing. It's also reacting to force fields differently, as in they seem to have much less influence. I don't see how I can add files here, but I've been rebaking scenes I setup in 2.8 in 2.9 with the values kicked up and while the basics are the same the overall flow is really different. I'm going to try 2.29A today.